# Have any way to change cancel url in paypal payment? (Magento Heidelpaycd edition)

Tags: magento-1.8, paypal

I am using module Magento Heidelpaycd edition.
Have any way to change this message to "cancel and return to my site". 
Look at picture.[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I received this answer. i hope this will help other.

our support can change this in Live mode in the merchants configuration.
There is no way for you to change it directly. Contact support@heidelpay.com for further questions on this.